# Scalable HTML-forms for different browsers

Tags: html, forms, web

What is the correct method to create scalable forms for different browsers and screen sizes (mobile phone browsers, iDevices, desktops, etc)? Or the only way is to create specific pages for each other?

I have an assignment to create a simple image upload and email send form. The form is used from different devices and I would like to have all form elements (buttons etc.) scalable and sized correctly in each browser.

Comment: I suggest researching "reactive design" and "reactive web design".

Comment: s/reactive/responsive will get you more results

Answer (score 2):

By using css media queries...basically in your css file you set up a certain width of browser window and you place correct styles in that css block:

```
@media (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Whenever width of a browser window is between 520px and 699px body background will be red

Try looking into 'responsive web design' and 'css media queries'.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/